# Combinatorial Analysis

Tags: math, combinations, permutation, combinatorics, factorial

I am having difficulty modeling a combinatorial analysis on a particular problem, I wanted to isolate some generic form, can anyone help me?

The problem is very simple to understand, it is a generalization of the problem: "How many permutations can be formed using 'n' items, for example: "1 2 3 4 5", which would be 5!"

The difference is that for each place I can use only a certain set of items and without repeating a certain item, eg:

```
[1, 2, 3] # I can only use these for first place
[2, 3, 4] # I can only use these for second place
[3, 4, 5] # I can only use these for third place
```

Examples of valid arrangements: **(1, 2, 3)** or **(3, 2, 5)**
Examples of invalid arrangements: **(2, 2, 3)**

I would like to find some calculation for this problem, I have solved the same using dynamic programming, but I believe that it is possible to isolate some mathematical method ..

The input is defined by **x** and **y**, **x** means the number of numbers in each group, **y** means the number of groups. The first group starts with **[1, .. x]**, the second group onwards begins with **[1 + j, .... x + j]** where j is the group that goes from 0 ... (y - 1), eg:

```
x = 3, y = 4
# represents the count of:
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 6]

x = 5, y = 3
# represents the count of:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

# And for this case, the valid numbers is (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 
# 3), (2, 4), (3, 2), (3, 4), so the answer is 7.
x=2, y=2
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: better at [math.se]?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you want. Do you want the total count or do you want to create all the possibilities?

Comment: Will: Yes, it would be better to post on the topic of math, but I am new here, I ended up failing to post ..

Kvantour: And I do need to count the number of valid numbers, I do not necessarily have to find them, but count how many are ..